# Heap exploitation with Glibc 2.12.1

Tags: glibc, exploit, heap-corruption, shellcode

I've been searching with no good results.

I wonder if the techniques explained in texts as Malloc Maleficarum or Malloc Des-Malleficarum are effective in glibc version 2.12.1.

In the second mentioned text is said that the techniques are tested in glibc version 2.7 and 2.8, so I don't really know if they will work with my glibc version. Of course I could test them, but, first, only by their own the techniques are really difficult and, on the other hand, if they don't work I wouldn't know if it would be because of the glibc version or my fault.

Moreover, I haven't found any actual heap **exploit**. And, also, I couldn't find the changes implemented through these glibc versions.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As with my other questions about this topic, given that nobody have answered, I will answer it just in case it will be useful for someone.

The first thing to say is that nowadays there are techniques of the Malloc Maleficarum that are already patched. For example, the House of Mind was patched in the glibc 2.11 so nowadays they are of no use.

But the most important thing is that in the majority of the techniques in the MM, you need the address of one buffer placed in the heap, therefore those techniques are completely useless in systems with aslr activated (all?), unless you can find a memory leak. But much more important is that if you are able to know that buffer address, you don't need any of the MM techniques, you can use the oldy unlink technique (with some tricks).

On the other hand, I've only found one exploit using one of the techniques explained in the MM (the house of mind). I haven't tested it, so try it at your own [1].

Another thing to be said, as my opinion after doing some research, MM was a mind blowing document, but in practice, the techniques explained on it a really difficult to apply in a real case. They have too many requisites and if you fulfill some of them, you can return to the unlink technique and forget about all the MM headaches.

P.S.: I feel dirty when setting my own answers as correct...

[1] https://sites.google.com/site/felipeandresmanzano/popplerPOC.tar.bz2

Comment: Hi, I would like to ask you some questions, but it looks like stackoveflow doesn't have a contact functionnality.

Comment: Please don't feel dirty marking your own answers as correct, It was useful for me.